# regex alternate select wrong match

Tags: c#, regex

I have names like this :

```
\\SRV\Share\TVS\My Super Tv Show\Season 11\S11E12 - some title.jpg
\\SRV\Share\TVS\My Super Tv Show\Season 11\12-sometitle.png
\\SRV\Share\TVS\My Super Tv Show\S11E12 -some title.fdf
\\SRV\Share\TVS\My Super Tv Show\Season 11-E12 - Some title.fdgfg
\\SRV\Share\TVS\My Super Tv Show\Season 11 Ep12 - Some Title.jpeg
\\SRV\Share\TVS\My Super Tv Show\11x12 - Some Title.jpeg
```

I need to retrieve `My Super Tv Show`, season number and episode number.

I tried many regex, last is :

```
.+\\.+\\(?<TvShow>.+?)[. -\\]+?((Season (?<Season>\d+)\\[sS]\d+[eE])|([sS](eason )?(?<Season>\d+)[. -]*[eE]?p?[. -\\]*)|((?<Season>\d+)[xX]))(?<Episode>\d+)
```

it does not recover the tv show name from the first name, and gets only 2 instead of 12 for episode number (except for the last name)

Any help would be greatly appreciate :)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus ... for the show name, but not also Season/Episode. I would suggest to use a different regex for those.

Comment: @Fildor Yep, I didn't read the whole question, comment deleted...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Oh, I didn't mean it was bad. It matched the show name pretty well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also use 3 named capture groups without the alternations

```
\\(?<TvShow>[^\\]+)\\(?:S(?:eason)?\s*)?(?<Season>\d+)[\\Ex -](?:S\d+E|Ep?)?(?<Episode>\d+)
```

The pattern matches

- `\\` Match `\`
- `(?<TvShow>[^\\]+)` Capture any char except `\`
- `\\(?:S(?:eason)?\s*)?` Optionally match variations of Season
- `(?<Season>\d+)` Capture 1+ digits
- `[\\Ex -]` Match 1 of the listed chars
- `(?:S\d+E|Ep?)?` Optionally match `SE` and 1+ digits or `E` with optional `p`
- `(?<Episode>\d+)` Capture 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/olX41x/1)

[image]

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5c%28%3f%3cTvShow%3e%5b%5e%5c%5c%5d%2b%29%5c%5c%28%3f%3aS%28%3f%3aeason%29%3f%5cs*%29%3f%28%3f%3cSeason%3e%5cd%2b%29%5b%5c%5cEx+-%5d%28%3f%3aS%5cd%2bE%7cEp%3f%29%3f%28%3f%3cEpisode%3e%5cd%2b%29&i=%5c%5cSRV%5cShare%5cTVS%5cMy+Super+Tv+Show%5cSeason+11%5cS11E12+-+some+title.jpg%0d%0a%5c%5cSRV%5cShare%5cTVS%5cMy+Super+Tv+Show%5cSeason+11%5c12-sometitle.png%0d%0a%5c%5cSRV%5cShare%5cTVS%5cMy+Super+Tv+Show%5cS11E12+-some+title.fdf%0d%0a%5c%5cSRV%5cShare%5cTVS%5cMy+Super+Tv+Show%5cSeason+11-E12+-+Some+title.fdgfg%0d%0a%5c%5cSRV%5cShare%5cTVS%5cMy+Super+Tv+Show%5cSeason+11+Ep12+-+Some+Title.jpeg%0d%0a%5c%5cSRV%5cShare%5cTVS%5cMy+Super+Tv+Show%5c11x12+-+Some+Title.jpeg)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) I have tweaked it a bit `\\(?<TvShow>[^\\.-]+)[\\ -]*(?:[sS](?:eason)?\s*)?(?<Season>\d+)[\\eExX -.](?:[sS]\d+[eE]|[eE]p?[. -]?)?(?<Episode>\d+)` so that it can work with more names (such as `D:\Users\Test\Pictures\My Super Tv Show - 12x12 -SomeTitle.bnbg
`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^\\\\(?:[^\\]+\\){3}(?<TvShow>[^\\]+)\\(?:Season\s*(?<Season>\d+)\\(?:(?<Episode>\d+)|S\d+E(?<Episode>\d+))|Season\s*(?<Season>\d+)[\s-]*Ep?(?<Episode>\d+)|S(?<Season>\d+)E(?<Episode>\d+)|(?<Season>\d+)x(?<Episode>\d+))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5C%5C%5C%5C%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%5C%5C%5D%2B%5C%5C%29%7B3%7D%28%3F%3CTvShow%3E%5B%5E%5C%5C%5D%2B%29%5C%5C%28%3F%3ASeason%5Cs*%28%3F%3CSeason%3E%5Cd%2B%29%5C%5C%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3CEpisode%3E%5Cd%2B%29%7CS%5Cd%2BE%28%3F%3CEpisode%3E%5Cd%2B%29%29%7CSeason%5Cs*%28%3F%3CSeason%3E%5Cd%2B%29%5B%5Cs-%5D*Ep%3F%28%3F%3CEpisode%3E%5Cd%2B%29%7CS%28%3F%3CSeason%3E%5Cd%2B%29E%28%3F%3CEpisode%3E%5Cd%2B%29%7C%28%3F%3CSeason%3E%5Cd%2B%29x%28%3F%3CEpisode%3E%5Cd%2B%29%29&i=%5C%5CSRV%5CShare%5CTVS%5CMy%20Super%20Tv%20Show%5CSeason%2011%5CS11E12%20-%20some%20title.jpg%0D%0A%5C%5CSRV%5CShare%5CTVS%5CMy%20Super%20Tv%20Show%5CSeason%2011%5C12-sometitle.png%0D%0A%5C%5CSRV%5CShare%5CTVS%5CMy%20Super%20Tv%20Show%5CS11E12%20-some%20title.fdf%0D%0A%5C%5CSRV%5CShare%5CTVS%5CMy%20Super%20Tv%20Show%5CSeason%2011-E12%20-%20Some%20title.fdgfg%0D%0A%5C%5CSRV%5CShare%5CTVS%5CMy%20Super%20Tv%20Show%5CSeason%2011%20Ep12%20-%20Some%20Title.jpeg%0D%0A%5C%5CSRV%5CShare%5CTVS%5CMy%20Super%20Tv%20Show%5C11x12%20-%20Some%20Title.jpeg&o=m)

[image]

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\\\\` - a `\\` string
- `(?:[^\\]+\\){3}` - three occurrences of one or more chars other than `\` and then a `\`
- `(?<TvShow>[^\\]+)` - Group "TvShow": one or more chars other than `\`
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing groups:

  - `Season\s*(?<Season>\d+)\\(?:(?<Episode>\d+)|S\d+E(?<Episode>\d+))` - `Season`, 0+ whitespaces, one or more digits ("Season" group), `\`, then either one or more digits ("Episode" group) or `S`, one or more digits, `E`, one or more digits ("Episode" group)
  - `|` - or
  - `Season\s*(?<Season>\d+)[\s-]*Ep?(?<Episode>\d+)` - `Season`, zero or more whitespaces, one or more digits ("Season" group), zero or more whitespace/hyphens, `E`, an optional `p`, one or more digits ("Episode" group)
  - `|` - or
  - `S(?<Season>\d+)E(?<Episode>\d+)` - `S`, one or more digits ("Season" group), `E`, one or more digits ("Episode" group)
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<Season>\d+)x(?<Episode>\d+)` -one or more digits ("Season" group), `x`, one or more digits ("Episode" group)
- `)` - end of the group.

Comment: Thank you for this answer and your explanations, it works well for the list I have provided.I upvote it, but I mark @The fourth bird's anwer as good because it is more concise and works with local paths

Comment: @CFou If you remove `^\\\\(?:[^\\]+\\){3}`, it will work in a similar way. I only kept it because you had `\\.+` in your pattern.